# In Scripted Pipeline (pulling Jenkinsfile from SCM) approach, how do we publish artifacts to Artifactory?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

In Scripted Pipeline (pulling Jenkinsfile from SCM) approach, how do we publish artifacts to `Artifactory`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After installing [Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in) in Jenkins, the below code snippet did the trick for me.

```
rtUpload (serverId: "server-id",
            failNoOp: true,
            spec:
                    """{
              "files": [
                        {
                          "pattern": "build/libs/*.jar",
                          "target": "libs-release"
                        }
                     ]
            }"""
    )
```

Comment: Can someone help me understand why this is marked as negative vote?

Comment: you just repeated the previous answer without adding any new information. On the contrary, you omitted the important link to more information.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Artifactory Jenkins Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins). It extends the pipeline DSL with objects related to Artifactory, such as, well, `Artifactory` :D

Here's an example from the docs:

```
def server = Artifactory.server 'my-server-id'

def uploadSpec = """{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "bazinga/*froggy*.zip",
      "target": "bazinga-repo/froggy-files/"
    }
 ]
}"""
server.upload spec: uploadSpec
```

Comment: @user10802791 while you do need 15 reputation for upvote, you can accept the answer without it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work